# Why is the drag force proportional to $v^2$ and defined with a factor of $1/2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, conventions, drag

$$Drag = \frac{1}{2}C_d \rho Av^2$$

I understand that the strength of the drag depends on the density of the fluid the body passes through, the reference area of the body, the [drag coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient), and the velocity of the object.

I don't, however, understand the 1/2 and the $v^2$ in the equation.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question.  For example why don't we just make $C_D$ half of what we currently use and remove the 1/2 altogether.

Comment: The Factor $\frac{1}{2} \rho\,v^2$  is obtain form the stagnation (dynamic) pressure

Comment: Keep in mind that this drag rule is not universal. It applies for Reynolds numbers from about 1000 up (even then in some regimes the $v^2$ dependence is not exact, though this is usually expressed by varying the drag coefficient rather than by changing the form of the expression).

Answer (score 9):

In short, the squared speed $v^2$ appears in the equation because when moving faster, you increase both

- how much momentum ($p=mv$) that is transferred to the air molecules (they must be moved away faster) *and*
- how much air that must be moved away (because you sweep through more air per second).

Increasing the speed means increasing *both* of these factors that both make it tougher to fall. Thus, speed appears "twice", so to say.

The half $\frac 12$ that also appears in the equation, is - as others also point out - due to the drag coefficient $C_d$ being neatly written as $C_d=\frac{D}{Aq}$, where $q=\frac12\rho v^2$ is the dynamic pressure, an important aerodynamic property.

Sure, you could have included the half in the drag coefficient to simplify the drag formula. But you would simultaneously complicate the relationship $C_d=\frac{D}{Aq}$. You could also ask, why there is a half in $K=\frac12 m v^2$. Why isn't that half just included in the mass $m$? Well, because then many other relationships that include $m$ would become more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

The drag force is doing negative work on the object that it is decelerating.  By the work/kinetic-energy theorem, the work done is equal to the change in kinetic energy that the object experiences.  Since kinetic energy is defined as $E_k = 1/2 mv^2$, you can expect the "1/2" and the $v^2$ terms to show up in the equation.

Comment: Ah, I haven't learned the kinetic energy formula yet.

Comment: It still does leave an interesting question of why we keep the 1/2 and don't just account for it with the drag coefficient.

Comment: Maybe and maybe not.  I would rather keep the 1/2 in the formula so I could associate it with a kinetic energy term.  When I taught high school physics, there were a few instances when kinetic energy was involved, and a 1/2 showed up in the denominator of the answer.  From a math viewpoint, you don't want fractions in the denominator, but I told students to leave it there so people could recognize that kinetic energy was involved.

Comment: @JMac i think it is the same reason why kinetic energy is 1/2 mv^2 and not just mv^2, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs m and v have many other uses, so the 1/2 relationship there is needed for consistency everywhere.  $C_D$ is just a constant to fit different geometries to the drag equation.

Comment: It's not so much consistency but a matter of direct application to kinematics. Systems which move, must always relate to kinetic energy, which is why the 1/2 must be applied.

Answer (score 4):

Adding just a bit to the previous answer, I believe that the drag coefficient definition is based on the dynamic pressure term in [Bernoulli's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle#Incompressible_flow_equation), $\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$. Thus dependence on velocity squared is expected, and is often observed. However, fluid flow is complicated, and $C_d$ determined empirically in many cases varies with flow velocity, and Reynolds number, depending on boundary layer transition from laminar to turbulent flow, form drag, wake, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar question if you would ask - Why kinetic energy is defined as $E_k = 1/2~m v^2$. The answer is below.

Elementary work is :
$$
\begin{align}
dW &= F \cdot dr 
\\&= F\frac {dr}{dt} dt
\\&=Fv~dt
\\&=m\frac {dv}{dt}v~dt
\\&=mv~dv 
\end{align}
$$

Now integrate both sides :

$$ \int dW = m \int v~dv  $$

Which gives :

$$W=E_k=1/2~mv^2$$

Thus the answer of why kinetic energy is proportional to $v^2$ and has half factor 1/2 in it, is that it is due to integration.