# Why is the $\frac{1}{2}$ significant in $\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 C_d A$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, conventions, drag

The formula for drag force is $F_D=\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 C_d A$. Why is the $\frac{1}{2}$ significant here? I think that the [drag coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient) $C_d$ already serves the purpose.

Is it for a historical reason?

Comment: There is a good discussion of this factor in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/487220/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the drag force proportional to $v^2$ and defined with a factor of $1/2$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/487220/)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it was initially shown that the drag force is proportional (under certain conditions) to the *dynamic pressure* $q$ and the *frontal (projected) area* $A$. The proportionality constant of this relationship is what we call a *drag coefficient* $C_D$.

$$F_D\propto qA\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad F_D=C_DqA$$

Nice and neat. It turns out that this paramter $C_D$ depends largely on frontal shape in particular but also on several other factors involved with the flow over the surface.

Now since the dynamic pressure already is defined as $q=\frac12\rho v^2$, there comes the half.

$$F_D=C_DqA=C_D\,\underbrace{\frac12 \rho v^2}_qA$$

The drag coefficient *could* have been defined to include the half. But that would remove the visually clear involvement of the dynamic pressure in the equation. Also, since the drag coefficient now [is involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient) in many other relationships throughout aerodynamical science, changing its definition in order to simplify *this* equation might complexify *other* relationships.